# Using CopyRaster in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

I need to remove white background around a pack of rasters. When I try Copy Raster from toolbox it works perfectly, but when I try batch processing or iterator in ModelBuilder, I have rasters with black background. It seems like one of parameters (ignore background value) don't used in model.

Comment: Looks like the missing or incorrect parameters passed into copy raster function. Could you please share the copy raster function defined in your arcpy script.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Also, the OP is not talking about arcpy, therefore no script is needed, but I aknowledge that he could give some more info (e.g. printscreen) of what he tried.

Comment: You need processing log or script with parameters?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.